# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/event.3"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, patch, form-for

I am trying to do an update action using bootstrap modal UI for my app. However, the route that i'm getting after clicking Submit button in the update form is always sending to event.3 instead of event/3.

My rake routes shows that PATCH action is directed to events/:id . I am not sure why after clicking the submit button in the form, it is sending /event.3 accoridng to the log. Can some one please explain to me what am I doing wrong ?

My full calendar JS code:

```
select: function(start,end){
    $.getScript('/event',function(){})

    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect')
},

eventClick: function(event){
    var url = 'events/' + event.id + '/edit';
    $.getScript(url,function(){});
    console.log(url);
}
```

ROUTES:

```
resources :events, only:[:create, :index]
get '/event', to: 'events#new', as: '/event'
get 'events/:id/edit', to: 'events#edit'
patch 'events/:id', to: 'events#update'
```

RAKE ROUTES:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action              
events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
       POST   /events(.:format)          events#create
 event GET    /event(.:format)           events#new
       GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
       PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
```

CONTROLLER :

```
def edit
  @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])   
end

def update    
  @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
  @event.update_attributes(event_params)   
end
```

HTML FORM

```
<div class="modal fade" id='edit_event'>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class ="modal-content custom" id="edit_event">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h1 class="modal_header_font"> Update Event </h1>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_for @event, :remote => true do |f| %>
            <% if @event.errors.any? %>

              <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">The form contains <%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %></div>
                <ul>
                  <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li>* <%= msg %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <% end %>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Title</b></label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <%= f.text_field :title, :class =>"form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Location</b></label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <%= f.text_field :location, :class =>"form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Start</b></label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <%= f.date_select :start, :class =>"form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>End</b></label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <%= f.date_select :end, :class =>"form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Remarks</b></label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <%= f.text_area :description, :class =>"form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.submit "Send", :class =>"col align-self-center btn custom_primary" %>
          </div>

          <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

When you use form_for(@event), what is called to compute the url in the end is [polymorphic_url](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url). As you can see from "Functionality" section:

```
# an Article record
polymorphic_url(record)  # same as article_url(record)

# a Comment record
polymorphic_url(record)  # same as comment_url(record)

# it recognizes new records and maps to the collection
record = Comment.new
polymorphic_url(record)  # same as comments_url()

# the class of a record will also map to the collection
polymorphic_url(Comment) # same as comments_url()
```

In your case, since you're using `form_for @event`, **what this mean is that you are calling `event_url(@event)`**

In your routes you have this:

```
get '/event', to: 'events#new', as: '/event'
```

So, what is actually called to compute the URL form is `/event` instead of `event/:id`

**How to fix**

I recommend you to use rails conventions and just use `resources :events`. But a fast fix should be something like this:

1) Update

```
get '/event', to: 'events#new', as: '/event'
```

to

```
get '/event', to: 'events#new', as: 'new_event'
```

2) Update

```
patch 'events/:id', to: 'events#update'
```

to

```
patch 'events/:id', to: 'events#update', as: 'event'
```

If you do this, remember to update your old references to `'events#new'`.

Comment: Thanks muZk ! If it's not too much to ask, I'm using devise for authentication and i would like to have my URL to have something like /:user_id/:event_id. But at the same time, i don't wan the event_id to skip the increment. For example 2 users : U1 & U2. U1 posted 1 event and U2 posted another after U1. I would like to have U1/event_ID=1 and U2/event_ID=1

Comment: What you have to do is basically add a new integer column to events, let say "number", and it is auto generated based on the count of events of the user. And in controller update the queries. Something like this should guide you a bit: https://gist.github.com/muZk/961af2e4c90fe48a399313b6858c21e2

Answer (score 0):

This line...

```
<%= form_for @event, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Is doing a patch or put to your `@event` show path.

You can change your routes to give edit an explicit name...

```
get 'events/:id/edit', to: 'events#edit', as: 'edit_event'
```

Then

```
<%= form_for edit_event_path(@event), :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve ! Learnt a few things there. But my the data are gone after doing that. However i followed muZk's approach and it works.